# Maven with Ant wrapper error - main class path

Tags: java, maven, ant

I'm attempting to compile my companies codebase using Maven which is wrapped in an Ant launcher for backwards compatibility reasons. I am running Oracle Linux 6.6, Java 1.7 u79-b14, Ant 1.7.1 and Maven 3.0.5 which are versions dictated to me by the enterprise infrastructure team.

When I set `JAVA_HOME` I get the following error when executing Ant `Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher` but if `JAVA_HOME` is commented out then Ant seems to run just fine.

```
#~/.bashrc

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
export MAVEN_HOME=/usr/share/maven
export M2_HOME=/usr/share/maven
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024m"
export BUILD_CHROOT="/home/builduser/builds"
```

Included to help is the location at which Java is installed.

```
[builduser@iaas-a-jen03 ~]$ which java
/usr/bin/java

[builduser@iaas-a-jen03 ~]$ ls -la /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jun 30 11:58 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java

[builduser@iaas-a-jen03 ~]$ ls -la /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Jun 30 11:58 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
```

Comment: I would recommend to take a look at the [maven-wrapper](https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper). Apart from that i don't see any advantage of a Ant wraper instead of using Maven directly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by following the steps found in this blog post... http://pkolomeitsev.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/apache-ant-error-could-not-find-or-load.html

`ant --execdebug` was the key to creating the right folders. Then I just had to make sure that `java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.x86_46` was installed and voila!